# Error while importing latest facebook 4.0.1 sdk into eclipse for login as facebook functionality

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

Error Logs

AppLink cannot be resolved to a type
DialogFragment cannot be resolved to a type
Fragment cannot be resolved to a type

Sometimes it shows the error of android:textAllCaps not resolved.

I tried to run with the jdk 1.6 as well but not solving my problem.

Thanks
Vishvendu Palawat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook SDK 4.0.1 compile by jdk 1.7 higher. Just use jdk 1.7 for compile your app and facebook project.
If you want to try to compile by 1.6. You can download facebook-sdk project and repair any errors had been checked and rebuild it. But i dont recommend this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Me too facing the same issue today and found a way to fix those issues,

The Facebook SDK 4.0,1 is build in Android Studio and converted to Eclipse project so the libs folder is not included in the library.

So add `libs` directory in the FacebookSDK folder and add these files

```
 1. android-support-v4.jar
 2. bolts-android-1.1.2.jar
```

after adding clean the facebook project, the error will be resolved.

you can get the bolds-android-1.1.2.jar from old facebook library or get it from internet

and also you need to do the steps *Hoai Ba Dinh* said

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your sdk - java - eclipse setup is busted.

Few pointers:

- keep latest jdk path in the eclipse
- fetch latest sdk from sdk manager in eclipse
- Keep your Android Libraries up to date
- Migrate to Android Studio as soon as possible.

Comment: But my other project is running on the same environment its just when I import facebook sdk it gives this error.